# How to disable submit button if one of field is empty?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to disable submit button if one of field is empty.

button:

```
<b-button class="btn" pill @click="submit" :disabled="disableHandler(['login', 'password'])">
```

method:

```
disableHandler(f) {
        f.map((item)=>{
          if (this[item].length > 0) {
            return false;
          };
        });
        if (this.loading) {
          return true;
        }
        return true;
      }
```

method returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button:

```
<b-button class="btn" pill @click="submit" :disabled="!login || !password">
```

Comment: thx for idea, it works <b-button class="btn" pill @click="submit" :disabled="!this.login || !this.password || this.loading">

Comment: In vue template, you don't have to use `this`. You can access directly to your data without `this`. Remove it from `this.login`, `this.password`... If my answer is good for you, can you validate it? Thx.